# SFINAE with std::enable_if and std::is_default_constructible for incomplete type in libc++

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, sfinae, libc++

I just observed a strange issue with libc++ when using SFINAE to detect if a templated type is default constructible.

The following is a minimal example I was able to come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Dummy;

template <>
struct Dummy<int>{};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_dummy : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_dummy<C, std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<Dummy<T>>::value>> : std::true_type{};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_dummy<int>{}() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_dummy<double>{}() << '\n';
}
```

It compiles and outputs the expected lines `true` and `false` when compiled with g++ or clang++ when using `libstdc++`. However when I try to compile it with libc++ (i.e. `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++1z test.cpp`) I get the following error:

> /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2857:38: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
>        'Dummy'
>       : public integral_constant
>
> /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:3166:14: note: in instantiation of template class
>         'std::__1::is_constructible>' requested here
>       : public is_constructible<_Tp>
>
> test.cpp:14:43: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::is_default_constructible >'
>         requested here 
>    `struct has_dummy<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<Dummy<T>>::value>> : std::true_type{};`
>
> test.cpp:18:35: note: during template argument deduction for class template partial specialization
>         `'has_dummy<type-parameter-0-0, typename enable_if<std::is_default_constructible<Dummy<T> >::value,
>         void>::type>' [with T = double]`
>
> ```
>    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_dummy<double>{}() << '\n';
> ```
>
> test.cpp:5:8: note: template is declared here
>   `struct Dummy;`

Is this a bug in libc++'s implementation of `std::enable_if` or `std::is_default_constructible` or is what I'm doing somehow invoking undefined/implementation specific behaviour?

Best
Corristo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preconditions for `is_default_constructible` state quite clearly:

> N4140 § 20.10.4.3 [meta.unary.prop] / `is_default_constructible` row
>
> `T` shall be a complete type, (possibly *cv*-qualified) `void`, or an
>   array of unknown bound.

And according to the following, your program exhibits undefined behaviour:

> N4140 § 17.6.4.8 [res.on.functions] / 2
>
> the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - [...]
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for
>     that component.

Comment: In the library, breaking preconditions results in undefined behavior unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @T.C. well, it seems I learn something new from you almost every day :)  Is it fine now? I'm not sure whether res.on.functions or res.on.required applies. The latter has better name but mentions functions explicitly, and traits aren't functions, unless they use the word function differently