# std::is_constructible on incomplete types

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_constructible<A>::value << std::endl;
}
```

When I use [GCC 8.3](https://godbolt.org/z/81kWbF), this code compiles. However, when I use [Clang 8.0](https://godbolt.org/z/wd5-is), I get a compilation error that incomplete types cannot be used in type traits.

Which one is correct? Am I allowed to use `is_constructible` on an incomplete type (with an expected value of `false`), or am I not allowed to?

Comment: Related question [SFINAE with std::enable\_if and std::is\_default\_constructible for incomplete type in libc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821950/sfinae-with-stdenable-if-and-stdis-default-constructible-for-incomplete-type)

Comment: How would `is_constructible` determine if `A` is constructible if `A` is not a complete type?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If `A` isn't complete, we can't construct it (`A a;` on an incomplete class `A` causes a compiler error) - that's the way it was working in our code base in the past, but it appears that was just luck of the draw due to undefined behavior.

Comment: Re: "we can't construct it" -- type traits are about the properties of a type. It would be really disturbing if `std::is_constuctible<A>` changed its result depending on what headers you included. In one place it's constructible and in another it isn't?

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's a fair point that I hadn't considered - the original use case was a templated `class A` that only had specific parameters instantiated. We then used SFINAE with `std::is_constructible` so that only certain types of types were allowed through. This is easily done correctly by explicitly instantiating a default `class A` where constructors are explicitly deleted (which is what I've done), but the thought process was from that angle. Hadn't considered the (what should have been obvious) "forward-declared-class-that-actually-exists" angle...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The behavior is undefined.

> **[meta.unary.prop]**
>
> ```
> template <class T, class... Args> struct is_constructible;
> ```
>
> `T` and all types in the parameter pack `Args` shall be complete types,
>   (possibly cv-qualified) void, or arrays of unknown bound.

[That's a precondition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/meta.unary.prop) of the meta-function. A contract that your code violates. libc++ is being generous by notifying you.

---

Mind you, that putting that precondition there and leaving it undefined otherwise is for a reason. A program where two points of instantiation of a template have different meanings is [ill-formed NDR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52264984/817643). The only sane course of action is demand complete types. And after all, that's when the trait is most useful anyway.

Answer (score 18):

Your code causes undefined behavior.

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) states:

> `template< class T, class... Args >
>   struct is_constructible;`
>
> T and all types in the parameter pack Args shall each be **a complete type**, (possibly cv-qualified) void, or an array of unknown bound. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 8):

Your code has undefined behavior.  Per [[meta.unary.prop] table 47](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta.unary.prop#tab:type-traits.properties) `std::is_constructible` requires

> `T` and all types in the template parameter pack `Args` shall be **complete types**, *cv* `void`, or arrays of unknown bound.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>